# Can I set up a Google Sheet to copy everything from another sheet, except for cells with a specific word count?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Form set up, and anybody can submit a response an unlimited number of times. (It has to be this way. I can't make people log in.)
The issue is that there's a spammer who's using some website or bot to submit thousands of spam responses. I've tried using the captcha add-on from xfanatical (which adds a question that makes them fill out a particular code, which changes every minute), but the spammer figured out how to get past that.

One thing I've noticed, though, is that each spam submission is exactly 100 words. So one way I can think of to solve this is to have a sheet that returns all rows from the "Responses" sheet except for the rows where the submission is exactly 100 words.

**Edit**: I've also noticed that all the **submissions start with a space**, so that could be used too.

Comment: Is this an Excel problem? Why tag Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that your `Responses 1` sheet has the answers in columns `A, B, C, D, E` etc. all the way to column `Z`
Let us now suppose that it is **column `C`** that holds the answers that **start with a space**.

**Follow these steps:**

- Please create another tab and name it `Clean`.
- Place the following formula in another cell `A1`


  ```
  =QUERY('Clean'!A1:Z,"select * where not C matches '\s.*'")
  ```
- Enjoy a spam free answer sheet :)

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62013907/can-i-set-up-a-google-sheet-to-copy-everything-from-another-sheet-except-for-ce/62015992#comment109701357_62015992) by the OP, one can also use

```
=QUERY('Responses 1'!A1:Z,"select * where not C starts with ' '")
```

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: I assume I should put the query in `A1` of the `Clean` tab, and write "Responses" (the name of the tab with the responses) rather than "Clean" in the query? I have columns `A` and `B` in the responses sheet, with `A` being the timestamp and `B` being the response, so I put in `=QUERY(Responses!A1:B,"select * where not B matches '\s.*'")` to the `Clean` sheet, but it still copied all the rows where the response starts with a space

Comment: Actually, I slighted edited the query to be `=QUERY(Responses!A1:B,"select * where not B starts with ' '")` and that worked! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: *"I assume I should put the query in...."*  My mistake. Sorry and thank you. **BUT**. In your case, `matches '\s.*'` does exactly the same as `starts with ' '`. Strange it didn't work. In any case, glad it worked for you.